# Can't find proper image path

Tags: java, image

I just googled and searched this site, found a lot of stuff, but either did I not understand the principle or am doing it wrong.

Actually the Class and the Image are not in the same directory, but to ease things for testing, I put the image into the same folder as my class.

These are the two lines:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("gimmick_facepalm.png");

System.out.println(img.getIconWidth() + " " + img.getIconHeight());
```

Output is always -1 -1, so I suspect that Java does not read in the image.

Hint or solution would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: use absolute path instead of just image name.

Comment: Look into Java's [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify an absolute path (ie. C:/... under windows), the current directory will be the directory where the program was executed, not the class folder (your project root in eclipse for instance, or where your were when you invoked the "java" command).

Furthermore, you can access files in a package of the classpath like so:

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("name/of/package/"+fileName).toURI());
```

Or directly with ImageIcon:

```
new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("name/of/package/"+fileName));
```

Comment: okay, but since we are working as a group using git, an absolute path will bring problems to every other member since they do not use the same folder to download to project to

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not even `ImageIcon imageFacepalm = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename));` where filename is a String with the images name in the same directory works. Why is that?

Comment: @N30 look more closely: you need to put the package in path form in front of your file, ie. "com/myapp/gimmick_facepalm.png"

Comment: Thank you all, but all the help doesnt work when the real issue is PEBKAC. I remembered saving the image as .png, but it was actually .jpg. DOH! Nonetheless, Thanks for effort ! (Besides that, I had to add src/ to any relative path I had used)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("gimmick_facepalm.png");
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);

System.out.println(img.getIconWidth() + " " + img.getIconHeight());
```